# How do I import data from a .xlsx file to Filemaker Pro if the "matching" field has trailing zeros?

Tags: excel, format, filemaker, import-from-excel

I am importing data from an Excel file into a Filemaker Pro database (FMP 12.0 v5 for Mac). I am using the imported data to "Update matching records in found set". However, the field that I am using to match occasionally contains trailing zeros.

When importing, FMP does not match the fields correctly, because it ignores the trailing zeros.

To explain further: the field in the database is a calculated text field, "courseID.personID", determined by concatenating the numerical "courseID" and "personID" fields (with a dot in between them). The field in my Excel file is formed similarly, using Excel formulae. Some "personID" values end in a zero, e.g. 120, and so courseID.personID becomes something like "123.120". I am matching the Excel field to the FMP field.

I first noticed this was happening, and was very careful to go back to Excel and make a new file (to start fresh), select all cells and set format to Text. Then, I did a Paste Special from my original data, and selected Paste as Values. All the cells in the courseID.personID column gave a "number stored as text error", with the option to convert the text to numbers. I selected the option to ignore the error, to leave all the data stored as text, with the intention of preserving the trailing zeros.

Alas, the issue persists. So, does anyone have any ideas of how to force Excel to format and communicate the proper values? Or, is it an issue of making FMP interpret the data properly, maybe by adjusting field types?

Comment: Could you not simply use a different separator, e.g. `"|"`?  --- I  don't remember much about Excel, but I seem to recall something about forcing a number to text by prepending an apostrophe, i.e.`"'123.120"`. --- Yet another option is to embrace the behavior and make Filemaker do the same by setting the result type of the calculation to Number (assuming you don't have both "12" and "120").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the field in the database is a calculated text field,
>   "courseID.personID", determined by concatenating the numerical
>   "courseID" and "personID" fields (with a dot in between them). The
>   field in my Excel file is formed similarly, using Excel formulae.

Come to think of it, the simplest solution would be to eliminate the calculation fields and use the original values for the import:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! The suggestions from your other comment are useful, although might not work due to the peculiarities of my database. This, however, is exactly what I was looking for. Although I wish I could make FMP read the correct data from Excel, this gets around the issue completely. Just tried it out and worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch!